# Screen permanently black with broken proximity sensor and Proximity Sensor Accelerometer App

Tags: uninstallation, sensors, sony-xperia-z, proximity-sensor

My phone's proximity sensor is broken and constantly signals "covered". The screen turns black when I'm called.

I installed an app [Proximity Sensor Accelerometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stevenstanleybayes.proximitysensor) to solve this and played around with the features.

**Now my screen is permanently black.**

How can I disable or uninstall the app? Maybe remotely? Maybe install another app remotely to fix this?

I don't have usb debugging enabled on the phone. Plugging in the charger doesn't reactivate the screen.

Device: Sony Xperia Z2, not sure of Android version

Comment: It's a Sony Xperia Z2. The version is quite new but I don't know for sure. Can I find out from my computer via Playstore?

Comment: Hey, I now was able to restart the phone using power + volume up (couldn't restart before). Could disable the app. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can. Also maybe you have an idea on how to turn off my broken proximity sensor? But I could also do this in a different question or research first.

Answer (score 0):

The app settings are reset after the phone is restarted so I did this: power button + volume up.

Press it at the same time for a few seconds to turn off the screen without needing to use touch. Then start the phone and the app is reset.